# Git switch and pull new branch

Tags: git

I have a git branch cloned, lets say master, and I want to pull a new branch, lets say test.

When I pull master originally I am doing a --depth=1

Then when I pull the new branch I want to keep it shallow. so all i want to do is pull the history of the new branch that I am switching to.

I thought I could git clone master then just git pull test however this is returning unrelated history issues.

I just want to take the new branch no matter what, and I would like to see what files were pulled in as well as the difference of master and test. This could be an issue with the specific repo I am testing on, but I would not want this issue to come up in the future.

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: "unrelated history issues" doesn't sound good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advice for using the `--depth` parameter to `git clone` goes like this:

1. Don't do it.
2. (for Git experts only) Don't do it *yet*.

(with [apologies to Dr Jackson](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/99463/225719) ).

More seriously, `--depth` enables `--single-branch`.  If you don't understand `--single-branch`, you're already in trouble: if you don't know that `git pull` *means* `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, you're in even bigger trouble here.

There's nothing wrong with learning all of the things that go into these.  Then you'll be a Git expert and you'll get to move to step 2 above, where you measure the time difference between working with a very shallow repository and working with a deeper one or un-shallowed one, and when and how to use a shallow repository in such a way that everything else works right.  But until then, leave out the `--depth 1` entirely.  You'll get an ordinary repository, instead of a shallow repository, and everything else will work much better.  Git is already hard enough for most people to use; there's no need to tie yourself to a huge anchor as you go for a swim in the Git-sea.

> Is anything like this possible?

Yes, but it's nontrivial.  You'll need to:

- Undo each single-branch-ness, or override that part entirely (add `--no-single-branch` to get a shallow but all-branch clone).
- Use enough history—history *is* commits, of whatever depth required—so that Git has enough information to be able to do what you want.

If you leave out the `--depth`, you'll get a normal clone where all of this is much easier.

Comment: the git repo i was checking out has years and years of history that was taking hours to clone, but thank you for the help!

Comment: Ouch. Well, that's where you might want to spend a lot of time on learning more stuff! Maybe `--no-single-branch --depth=<some hundreds or thousands>` will do the job...